# Relationships analysis among variables through time

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, multivariate-analysis, multilevel-analysis

**CONTEXT**

I have plenty of clients in my loyalty program where I offer them to accumulate points through `X` different channels, and those points can be used/exchanged through `Y` different products I offer. Those points also have an expiration. I have a second-precision data about when the client acumulated, used/exchanged his points, or when some of his points expired. Each client has a `balance of points >= 0.

**Example:** For each different `X` source of points (`X1`, `X2` and `X3` for example, where for banking could be `X1=credit card use`, `X2=debit card use`, `X3=Money (which means the client bought points with money)`) I offer `Y` ways to exchange those points accumulated (`Y1=buy retail products with points`, `Y2=discount in financial products`, `Y3`, `Y4`).

**THE PROBLEM**

I want to understand the relationship among accumulations, exchanges, and expirations through time. As points accumulated can only be exchanged or expired, they will be correlated (right?). But as I include the variable time here I would like to find relationships like:

- *"A client that tends to accumulate by X1/X2/X3 tends to exchange points for Y1/Y2/Y3/Y4 each 5 months/weeks/days"*
- *"A client with expiration points approaching (2 weeks to expire? 2 months to expire?) is more likely to purchase points (X3) given that he doesn't have enough balance to exchange his current points for a certain product Y he wants"*
- *"A client tends to exchange/use his points with Y2 after 3 weeks (or months?) of purchasing some points (X3)."*

The table I'm building for this is (with `Year-Month` and `Client_id` as the key):

```
Year-Month: Monthly date
Client_id: Client ID
Initial_Balance: Initial balance of points at that month
SPA: Source of Point Accumulated (X1, X2, or X3)
Points accumulated: Quantity of points bought/acumulated given a SPA, client_id, and year-month
GPE: Group of Points Exchanged (Y1, Y2, Y3, or Y4)
Points exchanged: Quantity of points exchanged given a GPE, client_id, and year-month
Points expired: Quantity of points expired given a client_id and a year_month
```

**QUESTIONS**

1. As points accumulated can only be exchanged or expired, they MUST be correlated? Is there a counter-example you could imagine?
2. Is there a way or test to determine what is the best temporality to use for this? (years, semesters, months, weeks, days, hours, seconds)
3. What kind of test will allow me to find the relationships I'm looking for?

The main objective of all this is to build an ML model to increase revenues with this analysis helping to build the model approach.

PS: You can edit the tags if you see fit it could help to answer this question more appropriately

Comment: what do you mean by "correlated" in your first question ? (what are the supposedly correlated variables?). Regrading the other questions, your problem seems to be too specific for a generic "test" to be able to answer your questions. You will need to specify more precisely what are the quantities you wish to estimate and what are your assumptions on the temporal behavior

Comment: The supposedly correlated variables are accumulation (`X` or `Points accumulated`), exchanges (`Y` or `Points exchanged`), and expiration (`Points expired`). Why? Because if you accumulate points, you need to exchange them for something or they will expire. What do you mean with "what are the quantities I wish to estimate"? And what kind of assumptions on the temporal behavior do you mean? Could you give an example in order to understand and answer your questions? Thanks!

Comment: For example you could estimate the probabilities $P_{i,j}^t$ that points accumulated by channel $i$ would be exchanged by method $j$ within a time period $t$ ($n_i \times n_j \times n_t$ parameters) or you could model the time dependence with some parametric function e.g. $P_{i,j}(t) = P_{i,j}^0(t)e^{-\alpha t}$ with less parameters, etc.

Comment: You got me. I don't know. What do I know, is that I'm trying to find possible "causalities". For example, does the client accumulate points when does an exchange of certain product? (I have been researching and it's pretty difficult to conclude causality, but that's where I'm aiming to). My main question is: what causes that a client accumulate/purchase points? Are there main drivers (of products for exchange and expiration) that causes purchase of points? Is there a window where this "causality" is stronger?